# Find the number of words each consisting of $3$ consonants and $3$ vowels that can be formed from the letters of the word CIRCUMFERENCE.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of words each consisting of $3$ consonants and $3$ vowels that can be formed from the letters of the word CIRCUMFERENCE.In how many of these $c$'s will be together?

---

The consonants are $c,r,c,m,f,r,n,c$ and the vowels are $i,u,e,e,e$.
Number of ways of arranging 3 vowels$=\frac{3!}{2!}+1+3!=10$
I am stuck in counting the number of ways of arranging 3 consonants because $c$ is coming 3 times and $r$ is coming 2 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Arrangements of the vowels:**

You correctly calculated that the number of distinguishable ways to arrange three E's is $1$ and that the number of ways to arrange three different vowels is $3!$.  However, you calculated the number of arrangements with two E's incorrectly.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of selecting the positions of the two $E$'s and two ways of selecting the other vowel.  Hence, the number of arrangements with two E's is 
$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}$$
Hence, the number of ways of arranging the three vowels in the three positions selected for the vowels is 
$$3! + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1} + 1$$

**Arrangements of the consonants:**

*Case 1*: Three different consonants.

We can choose three of the five consonants, then arrange them in order in
$$\binom{5}{3} \cdot 3!$$ 
ways.

*Case 2*: Two different consonants.

We choose which of the two letters C or R is repeated, choose two of the three positions in which to place the repeated letter, then choose one of the other four letters to fill the open slot, which yields
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$
possible arrangements.

*Case 3*:  One consonant is used.

There is only one way to fill the three positions with a C.

Hence, the number of ways of arranging the consonants within their three selected positions is 
$$\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1} + 1$$

**Number of words consisting of three consonants and three vowels from the letters of the word CIRCUMFERENCE**

We choose three of the six positions for the vowels, arrange the vowels in the selected locations, then arrange the consonants in the three remaining positions, which yields
$$\binom{6}{3}\left[3! + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1} + 1\right]\left[\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1} + 1\right]$$

Answer (score 3):

You can have $0 ... 3$ $C$'s.

One way to arrange three $C$'s:  $CCC$.

Three ways to arrange two $C$'s and another consonant:  $CCX, CXC, XCC$.  $X$ is one of $R,F,M,N$, so $12$ total for this case.

Six ways to arrange one $C$ with two different consonants: $CXY, CYX, XYC, YXC, XCY, YCX.$  There are $_4C_2 = 6$ ways to pick two of four consonants, so $36$ total ways for this case.

Three ways to arrange one $C$ with the repeated consonant: $CRR, RCR, RRC$.

If there are no $C$, you can have two $R$'s or not.

There are nine ways to arrange two $R$'s and one non-$C$ consonant.

There are $24$ ways to arrange three different non-$C$ consonants.

So ... adding everything gives $1+12+36+3+9+24 = 85$ ways to arrange three consonants.

(I think you can actually get $13$ arrangements of vowels:  $eee, eei, eie, iee, eeu, eue, uee, ieu, iue, eiu, eui, uie, uei$.)

To continue then, pick the arrangement of consonants $(85)$, pick the arrangement of vowels $(13)$ and then pick the three places where the consonants will go in the order you've chosen $(_6C_3 = 20)$.  (The vowels fall into the remaining spaces in the order you've chosen already.)

The total number of $6$-letter words then is $85 \cdot 13 \cdot 20 = 22100.$

For the second part of the question, there are $4$ ways to have three $C$'s together, and $13$ orderings for the vowels, so $52$ total ways.